# What is the equivalent Cocoa window level of Carbon kUtilityWindowClass?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, macos-carbon

i am working on a cocoa application that creates both normal cocoa windows and cocoa windows that are initialized with carbon windows. All windows should be floating above all applications. For the cocoa windows i set the window level to NSTornOffMenuWindowLevel, and for the carbon windows i use kUtilityWindowClass. Both works fine, windows are floating above other applications, but the problem is that carbon and cocoa windows don't have the same window level, so carbon windows will always float on top of cocoa windows. Is there a way of giving both window types the same window level without losing the floating above other apps? I guess since kUtilityWindowClass seems to be the only window class which enables floating about other apps in carbon, i am looking for its equivalent in cocoa... Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you look in NSWindow.h, you'll see that Cocoa window levels are defined in terms of Core Graphics window levels, e.g., `NSFloatingWindowLevel` is defined as `kCGFloatingWindowLevel`.  If you look at where these window levels are defined in CGWindowLevel.h, one of the choices is `kCGUtilityWindowLevel`.  That would be my guess as the equivalent of `kUtilityWindowClass`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly, but you could experiment. I would try `NSModalPanelWindowLevel` (one above  `NSTornOffMenuWindowLevel`), `NSMainMenuWindowLevel`, `NSStatusWindowLevel`, and `NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel`, which are the other available levels from relatively lower to highest.